# Resolving Faraday law vs. Stokes law for a long, time-varying current-carrying wire

Tags: electromagnetism

A long wire carries a sinusoidally-time-varying current.  What is the $E$ field around (not within) the wire?  Assume quasi-stationary operation.

Conflict:

According to Faraday, the circulation of the $E$ field around a closed loop $ \oint \bf E \cdot \bf dl $ formed by a rectangle with sides parallel and orthogonal to the wire equals $ -\partial \phi/\partial t $, the time rate of change of the $B$ flux within the rectangle. This is clearly finite since the time-varying $H$ field pierces the rectangle everywhere within the rectangle.  So therefore the $E$ field cannot be identically zero everywhere outside the wire.

On the other hand, since there is zero charge density outside the wire, $ \nabla \times H = \epsilon \ \partial \bf E/\partial t = 0 $.  But that says there is no time-varying $E$ field outside the wire (which seems to be the generally accepted assumption).

So which is it? Is the $E$ field zero or does it satisfy Faraday?  And why not the other?

Comment: Why would the electric field be zero outside the wire? $\nabla\times\mathbf E = -\partial\mathbf B/\partial t$ so I would expect $\mathbf E$ to be non-zero outside the wire.

Comment: As I said, $ \nabla \times \bf H = 0 = \partial \bf D/\partial t $ so there can be no time-varying E field, and a constant E field is unimaginable sice H is sinusoidal.

Comment: Besides, you are in effect supporting Faraday which is fine, but we still have my comment above to answer.  That is the conflict.

Comment: Outside the wire $\mathbf J = 0$ so $\nabla\times\mathbf B = \mu_0\epsilon_0\partial\mathbf E/\partial t$. Since $\partial\mathbf E/\partial t$ can be non-zero the magnetic field can be non-zero as well. Your argument would seem to rule out EM waves in  vacuum. Bear in mind that the system you describe is a radio aerial.

Comment: By my computation, $ \nabla \times \bf H = 0 $.  I used cylindrical coordinates for which $ \nabla \times \bf H = \partial H_{\theta}/\partial r} + H_{\theta}/r = 0 in the z direction..  So $ \partial \bf E/\partial t $ is zero also.

Comment: Sorry about mess, not yet used to this latex.  My message boils down to curl H = 0 so E cannot be time-variant.

Comment: Your comment about an aerial is interesting but of course you can't apply Ampere's rule to finite-length antennas.  Not sure about further implications with infinite-length antennas.

Comment: If you could check my arithmetic in coming up with curl H in cylindrical coordinates, that would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quasi-static approximation I take to be a spatial constraint: $\omega r \sqrt{\epsilon\mu}\ll 1$. With that in mind we do a scale analysis of the two equations. Faraday gives us $E\sim\omega\mu I/r$, while the other gives $\omega \epsilon E\sim (0)\times I/r^2$. These are not inconsistent: the electric field from Faraday is higher order than the vanishing field from the curl $H$ equation.

Comment: Thank you, all.  Tricky business, time-varying E and H fields!